# How to count items in an array that's in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How do you count items in an array that's part of an array? I'm using Advance Custom Fields plugin in WordPress and my array `print_r(get_field('irl_today_entry'))` output looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [acf_fc_layout] => irl_today_website_entry
        [irl_today_website] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    ( data removed)

                [1] => Array
                    ( data removed )
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [acf_fc_layout] => irl_today_social_entry
        [irl_today_social] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    ( data remove )
                [1] => Array
                    ( data remove)
            )
    )
)
```

How do you only count items in [irl_today_social]? I've tried a lot of options that do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple entries with `irl_today_social` you might also use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$res = array_map(function($x) {
    return count($x);
}, array_column($arrays, "irl_today_social"));

print_r($res);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/tpEAO)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_reduce`,

```
array_reduce(get_field('irl_today_entry'),function($a,$b){
    return count($a["irl_today_website"]) + count($b["irl_today_website"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your array, get the [count](https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/func_array_count.asp) of your desired index, and add that to a counter.

```
 $count = 0;
 foreach(get_field('irl_today_entry') as $entry){
   $count = $count + count(entry['irl_today_social']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use "[Count](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-count-all-elements-in-an-array-in-php.php)" Function

### Here is the Solution:

Step 1: First get your array items of ['irl_today_entry'].
Step 2 Then Count your ['irl_today_social'] items.

Example:

```
foreach(get_field('irl_today_entry') as $entry){
   $socialData = count(entry['irl_today_social']);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to my understaing just simply try this

```
echo count($your_array[1]['irl_today_social']);
```