# How to count more than one items in array_column?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I asked a question called '[How to count items in an array that's in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656225/how-to-count-items-in-an-array-thats-in-an-array)' and now I need help on expanding from that question.

How do you count items in two arrays?

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [acf_fc_layout] => irl_today_website_entry
    [irl_today_website] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                ( data removed)

            [1] => Array
                ( data removed )
        )
)
[1] => Array
(
    [acf_fc_layout] => irl_today_social_entry
    [irl_today_social] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                ( data remove )
            [1] => Array
                ( data remove)
        )
)
)
```

And I use:

```
<?php $arrays = get_field('irl_today_entry');
$res = array_map(function($x) {
return count($x);
}, array_column($arrays, 'irl_today_website'));?>
```

to count items in `[irl_today_social]`. How do I count items in `[irl_today_social]` and `[irl_today_website]`?

I tried `array_column($arrays, "irl_today_social", "irl_today_website")` and it only counted items in `[irl_today_social]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map()` can be fed multiple arrays to work with. The first array `"irl_today_social"` elements are referenced by `$x`, the second `"irl_today_website"` by `$y` in this case.

Use following:

```
$res = array_map(function($x, $y) {
    $soc = count($x);
    $web = count($y);
    return ['soc' => $soc, 'web' => $web];
}, array_column($arrays, "irl_today_social"), array_column($arrays, "irl_today_website"));
```

`array_map()` will return an array with the count for each - the result sample output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [soc] => 2
            [web] => 3
        )

)
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/N7NRA)